# replacing text between brackets from text in file

Tags: server, sed, client

I have configured the server instance in code

```
"instance": [
   { "address": 127.0.0.1,
     "port": 6514
},
{"address": 127.0.0.1,
 "port": 6515
}
]
```

I'm also having file(/root/home/inst.txt) which has a format

```
{ "address": 127.0.0.1,
     "port": 6514
},
{"address": 127.0.0.1,
 "port": 6515
},
{"address": 127.0.0.1,
 "port": 6516
}
```

I want to replace server instances in code from file.
I had tried

```
 sed -e '/"instances": \[/,/\]/{/r /root/home/inst.txt/!d}'
```

but failed

Answer (score 2):

Really it would be better to use a tool that understands your (almost-but-not-quite JSON?) file format.

However I *think* what you want is

```
sed -e '/^"instance": \[/,/^]/{/^"instance": \[/{p;r /root/home/inst.txt' -e '};/^]/!d}' code
```

That is:

- match the range of lines between `^"instance": \[` and `^]` (note that I added start-of-line anchors; you may decide these are not necessary)
- **p**rint the first line of the range, then **r**ead and queue the contents of `inst.txt` for insertion at the end of the cycle
- delete lines in the range excluding the terminating `]`

Splitting the expression with `-e` prevents the `};/^]/!d}` portion from being treated as part of the file name to be read.